# Add a string in a <td> using jquery and conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

What do I want : When the user focus out the field, i would like to add a string in the  depending of an other . The  are in a table and the problem is that i have to build the string depending of the size of the table.
It would be really nice if you give some documentations to help me because im a bit lost..

HTML :

```
<table id="tableAssemblage" class="dataAssemblage" style="display: table;">
<thead>
<tr class="entete">
    <td>
        Type</td>
    <td>
        Nom</td>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <td class="centrer">
      <select name="typ_element_1" id="typ_element_1" 
      class="obligatoryAssemblage typ_element">
         <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
         <option value="EDITION">EDITION</option>
         <option value="ENCART">ENCART</option>
         <option value="INCARTO">INCARTO</option>
         <option value="INCPLUS">INCPLUS</option>
         <option value="OPP">OPP</option>
         <option value="SUPPLEMENTS" disabled="">SUPPLEMENTS</option>
     </select>                        
   </td>
   <td class="centrer">

      <input type="text" name="nom_element_1" id="nom_element_1" value="" 
      size="35" length="35" maxlength="35" class="obligatoryAssemblage 
      nomAssemblage">        
   </td>
```

The Table : [result in my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibqZo.png)

The jQuery/JS :

```
$(".nomAssemblage").focusout(function(){
  addApresFixNomElement();
});

function addSuffixNomElement(){
   // Parametres
   var rowCount = $('#tableAssemblage tr').length;
   var typElem = $(".typ_element").val();
   var nomAss = $(".nomAssemblage").val();
   var Suffix;
   var id;
   // Switch
   switch (typElem)
   {
    case 'EDITION':
        for(id=1; id<rowCount; id++){
            Suffix = "[EDI ->" + id + "]";
            $(".nomAssemblage").append(Suffix);
        }
        
        break;

    case 'ENCART':
        break;

    case 'INCARTO':
        break;
        
    case 'INCPLUS':
        break;
    
    case 'OPP':
        break;
        
    case 'SUPPLEMENTS':
        break;
}
```

}

The result i want : [This is what i want exaclty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mLF3.png)

Comment: what is the output

Comment: nothing is happening, and the console is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
$("#nom_element_" + id).val($("#nom_element_" + id).val() + " " + Suffix);
```

as [`$().append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) is to append elements (have also improved the logic as well):

```js
$(".nomAssemblage").focusout(function() {
  addSuffixNomElement();
});

function addSuffixNomElement() {
  // Parametres
  var rowCount = $('#tableAssemblage tbody tr').length;
  var typElem = $(".typ_element").val();
  var nomAss = $(".nomAssemblage").val();
  var Suffix = "";
  var id = 1;
  // Switch
  switch (typElem) {
    case 'EDITION':
      Suffix = "[EDI ->" + id + "]";
      break;

    case 'ENCART':
      Suffix = "[ENC ->" + id + "]";
      break;

    case 'INCARTO':
      //Suffix = "[INCA ->" + id + "]";
      break;

    case 'INCPLUS':
      //Suffix = "[INCP ->" + id + "]";
      break;

    case 'OPP':
      //Suffix = "[OPP ->" + id + "]";
      break;

    case 'SUPPLEMENTS':
      //Suffix = "[SUP ->" + id + "]";
      break;
  }
  for (id = 1; id < rowCount; id++) {
    $("#nom_element_" + id).val($("#nom_element_" + id).val().replace(/\[.*?\]/, '') + " " + Suffix);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableAssemblage" class="dataAssemblage" style="display: table;">
  <thead>
    <tr class="entete">
      <td>
        Type</td>
      <td>
        Nom</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="centrer">
        <select name="typ_element_1" id="typ_element_1" class="obligatoryAssemblage typ_element">
          <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
          <option value="EDITION">EDITION</option>
          <option value="ENCART">ENCART</option>
          <option value="INCARTO">INCARTO</option>
          <option value="INCPLUS">INCPLUS</option>
          <option value="OPP">OPP</option>
          <option value="SUPPLEMENTS" disabled="">SUPPLEMENTS</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="centrer">

        <input type="text" name="nom_element_1" id="nom_element_1" value="" size="35" length="35" maxlength="35" class="obligatoryAssemblage nomAssemblage">
      </td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```